# Difference between initializing a C-style string to NULL vs. the empty string

Tags: c++, c, string

Are these three equivalent:

```
char* p= NULL;
char* q = "";
char r[] = {'\0'};
```

I suspect the first one is different from the rest, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Is the second form, possible in C? Isn't `q` suppose to contain a character, instead of a string? How can it refer to some memory location, returned by `""`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Ahha, this looks meaningfull now :-) Glad you did that.

Comment: In second one, `q` is actually pointing to some read only memory that contains a '\0' character(for some compilers), though the third one can be modified any time(in any compiler). The first one is simply pointing to some reserved area of memory, which is checked by the compiler, if that area has been modified, then it raises somethingy like `NULL pointer exception`, don't know what they call it in C, I guess `NULL pointer reference` :-) I am just new to C language, so bare with me, if I committed some mistake :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char* p = NULL;
```

This assigns NULL to the **pointer** `p` which means that `p` does not point to any valid memory address.

```
char* q = "";
char r[] = {'\0'};
```

These both create empty strings and are basically equivalent. `q` points to a valid memory address, unlike `p` in the previous example. `r` is an array with an empty string.

Comment: The second line also implies an implicit cast from `const char*` to `char*`, which in C++ is at least deprecated.

Comment: @jogojapan Good point. Although, "implies an implicit cast" seems redundant.

Comment: Casting by definition is always explicit. @jogojapan

Comment: Also it might be worth mentioning that `char* q = "";` allocates read-only memory. A `q[0] = something` will fail.

Comment: @alk *Exactly*. You get read-only memory, and that's the point of deprecating the implicit conversion (which I admit to having called implicit cast). Do you really think splitting hairs over my wording will help anyone?

Comment: @jogojapan: In C the `const` does **not** imply a real *read-only* memory, where as defintion like `char * p = "";` does, that's why I added this. Moreover it's not about "*splitting hairs*", but to be accurate when using well defined terms/expressions. And finally it definitly was not my intention to criticise you personally! :-)

Comment: @alk, Ok sure. And yes, I admit "implicit cast" is not quite the most proper use of terminology, just like "implies..implicit" is not quite the most brilliant way of describing something, as Code-Apprentice pointed out. It's just that for a moment I felt we are discussing the finer points of my wording in the comment rather than the main point, which is that lines 2 and lines 3 above are *not* equivalent. (Not sure about "basically equivalent".)

Comment: There are other important differences.  Both `p` and `q` can be made to point to other strings later: `p = "elephant"; q = "mammoth";` (give or take issues with const-ness) — `p = q = r;` would be totally legitimate.  You can change the character that `r` contains: `r[0] = 'p';` or `*r = 'q';` but it is no longer a string (because it is not a null-terminated sequence of characters any more).  After either of the assignments to `r[0]`, it is dangerous to pass `r` to a function expecting a null-terminated string.  You could use `*r = *q;` and if you've not changed `q` yet, `r` remains a string.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>I'm answering for C++ even though the OP has *also* tagged the question as C. These are two different languages. It's not a good idea to conflate them.</sup>

This declaration:

```
char* q = "";
```

used a deprecated conversion in C++03, and became **invalid** in C++11. We're now at C++14.

---

These two declarations:

```
char* p= NULL;
char r[] = {'\0'};
```

are fundamentally different. The first declares a **pointer** and sets it null. The second declares an **array** of one item, which item is set to null.

---

Regarding

> **”** Are these three equivalent

the answer is no, not at all: one is just invalid, one declares a pointer, one declares an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* p= NULL; // initializes the character pointer to NULL
char* q = ""; // character pointer points to a valid string with null content
char r[] = {'\0'}; // character array having null content
```